# Project Reactor Kafka with parallel API Calls Issue

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, java-11, reactor-kafka

**Problem Statement :** Consume Million Records from Kafka & Spin the Parallel API calls ( 120 TPS )

i'm using project reactor kafka for Kafka Message Consumption ( 2 million records per hour ). Once i receive the kafka messages then I need to spin the parallel API calls ( 10 TPS ) to "abc.com/actuator". I tested the kafka part .. I'm able to consume the million records in 20 mins ( with 4 Kubernetes Pods ). But when i spin API calls everything going in **sequential** **but not parallel**. Also, API taking 1000ms to return response ( which adds the waiting time ). Can someone help to understand what's wrong in parallel API calls ? Thanks in advance.

```
ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> options =
        receiverOptions
            .subscription(Collections.singleton(topic))
            .addAssignListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsAssigned {}", partitions))
            .addRevokeListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsRevoked {}", partitions));
    final Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer, String>> messages = Flux.defer() -> {
    final Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>> receiver = 
    kafkaReceicer.create(options).receive();
    return Flux.<ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>create(emmitter -> {
           kafkaFlux.doOnNext(record-> {
            ReceiverOffset offset = record.receiverOffset();
            offset.acknowledge();
            emitter.next(record);
       }).blockLast();
  });
});

WebClient wc = WebClient.create("abc.com:8443");
Flux.from(messages).flatMap(event -> wc.get().uri("/actuator").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
.parallel(10).runOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe();
```

**Kubernetes configuration** :

**CPU** : 300m
**Memory** : 10Gi

Comment: I see 2 TPS in recent logs.. Also, Kafka CG Lag is stable + API calls are taking  long time to complete whole process.

Comment: It’s Reactive Kafka with Blocking API call

Comment: Do you have a github link to the project?